# What advanced parental control can I set up for my nephews' computer?

Tags: windows-10, parental-controls

I have two nephews. I decided to buy them each of them a computer build. This is for them to earn something online and for a little bit of entertainment. The problem is, though, one of them has a gaming addiction, and I fear this might result in him to just keep on playing games and stop working. The other one, though, we can trust to be responsible, but will also place measures on his computer so they can't just swap computers.

I don't want to take away their freedom during their free time, I just want that during the specified time they will work (or at least just not be able to do anything other than work).

Both of them are skilled (and bold) enough to reformat a computer so just OS level of control is not enough. I know that it is impossible to fully protect the system since they have access to both hardware and software, but I want to make it hard for them, so that if there is a serious attempt, we can then have a good grounds for an intervention.

Aside from implementing a BIOS password, what else can I do in Windows 10 to prevent access to programs or even all IP addresses (except some)? `Syskey` is being removed by Microsoft so I can't use that to protect the settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Parental controls only operate at the OS level. Your issue is one of maturity and self control, not of technical protection.

Comment: Modern Macs have a T2 chip that can prevent anyone from substantially changing the OS - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208330 - I don't know a great deal about modern Windows machines, but I'd investigate if they can have similar security; then just don't let them have admin accounts or know the passwords for them. That way regular Parental control apps will be able to keep them on the straight & narrow.

Comment: Trust me, it doesn't work. If you are serious, **AVOID ALL HOME SOLUTIONS**. This includes Microsoft Parental Controls and Windows Family Safety. They are a joke. I have probably found 101 ways to bypass them. If you are serious, at least use an enterprise solution, like Group Policy. And I don't mean Local Group Policy, I mean fully-fledged group policy

Comment: @InterLinked I am using windows 10 pro, Im using group policy,to disable cmd,shell,task manger and more. The MS parental control are truly a joke, i record the total usage time of a program but does not show what time of the day it is being using, there is no daily usage statistics. I mean a paid keylogger can do this and that is an additional feature aside being a keylogger